# remove focus on select element on change and also if not changed with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have the following code which removes the focus of a select menu when the selected item is changed:

```
$("select").change( function() {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

However, if I do not select a different option to the one that was already selected, the blur() function does not run... because nothing has changed.

Is there a "change or not changed" function??

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var c = 0;
$("select").bind('click', function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (c++ % 2 == 1)
    {
        console.log(c);
        $(this).blur();
    }
});

$('html').click(function() {
    if ($('select').is(':focus'))
        c = 1;
    else
        c = 0;
});
​
```

[jsfiddle.net/5eE8x](http://jsfiddle.net/5eE8x)

Updated.

Comment: What if the user closes the menu by clicking off it rather than selecting the same option? - and in addition, that doesn't seem to work in Safari

Comment: If I understood you, then I think the browser will use `blur` automatically (browser behaviour).

Comment: The click event doesn't trigger for me on Chrome

Comment: Yep, `option` is not triggered on click, just remove the `> option` and `.parent()`

Comment: On the same page @GuyDavid, you may read: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

Comment: @Cybrix Thanks for noticing, I just came across that, so I changed to `bind`

Comment: Have you tried this in firefox? It doesn't work for me - it just deselects as soon as you've selected it.

Comment: This has no effect when navigating by keyboard.  That's likely a good thing.

Comment: Your latest update works assuming you've not clicked anywhere else on the page first. If I click in the white space, then use the dropdown, it keeps focus.

Comment: Think this one is taking a step back. It keeps focus all the time. I see what you're doing, I just can't get my head around what's needed to get it working in all instances.